# How to convert a texture in to different format for a customised human head model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a human head texture (and head mesh .obj) which is generated from an image using Deep Learning. I have a human body model (mesh .obj) which I need to apply the texture to. I need to apply the following texture format

[image: texture format for the whole body]
[image: texture for the whole body]
[image: SMPL female 3D body model]

[taken from Github](https://github.com/thmoa/semantic_human_texture_stitching)

**Then I need to apply the following head texture format to the above human body model. How can I convert head texture model to the whole body texture's head?**

[image: Head texture format]
[image: texture of the head]
[image: flame 3D head model]

[taken from Github](https://github.com/TimoBolkart/TF_FLAME)

**EDIT 1**

PS: two textures belongs to two input images(two persons). I just want to know how to convert the mapping between two UV maps of the head part

**EDIT 2**

Added the 2d images of meshes

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to find the names of these texture formats?

Comment: What do you need? The screenshots show **UV maps** not textures.

Comment: I have textures too, I need a mapping between these two UV maps. I need to convert the texture2(which has the UV map of second image) to texture1(which has the UV map of first image)

Comment: Each UV face represents a mesh face.  How similar are the meshes?

Comment: @batFINGER added the 2d images of the meshes to the OP